# passing a struct pointer to a function segfault C FREEBSD

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, freebsd

I am trying to port my C GNU/Linux code to FreeBSD. At first I thought it wouldn't compile and act abnormally, but it didn't act up on me because it didn't use functions that the other OS does not have native to it. Although it compiles fine (no errors or warnings using `-Wall`) the application keeps seg faulting on a line that works normally as intended on a GNU/Linux install.

What I am doing is creating a pointer to a struct and then passing the pointer to a function as a void pointer and then recreating it inside the function.

ex:

```
typedef struct
{
   int i;
}some_struct;

int main()
{
   some_struct *test = malloc(sizeof(some_struct));
   test->i = -1;
   function(test);

return 0;
}

void *function(void *prarm)
{
   some_struct test = *((some_struct *)param);  //segfaults on this line.
   free(param);


return NULL;
}
```

On my GNU/Linux install this would allow me to recreate the struct with the passed pointer data locally inside the function and allow me to free the `malloc`ed memory from `main()` but on FreeBSD it seg faults and I do not know why.

If I break at `function` in `gdb` and type

```
p *(some_struct *)param
```

It successfully prints out my command struct that is created from the pointer and all its variables from inside the function.

Im at a lost at why this is working  GNU/Linux and seg faulting on my FreeBSD test machine.

Thanks for any help towards this problem I am having.

Comment: Posting GCC (or CLang?) flags would be helpful, too.

Comment: This is not the real code. The problem is in some other portion you omitted.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile, and in fact, the `gdb` print cmd you quoted uses a completely different structure name from your code posted. Please post the *real* code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @cnicutar: sorry for not posting the actual code. The entire project is 1300 lines long so far and I didnt want to swamp you guys with useless code. I tried to minimize my code into how I am calling my function and the function itself in its entirety. Hopefully that can help you guys help me better. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @randynewfield, is speedtest_cmd declared on one of your headers (or in code you left out)? If not you should try to add a declaration. What architecture are you building for?

Comment: @jimhark yes everything is declared (it runs flawlessly on a GNU/Linux machine). I get no compile errors on FreeBSD nor GNU/Linux

Comment: `buff` and `data` are too big to be in the function. Move them outside or make them `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason for it to segfault, especially if `-Wall` is silent.

One thing that bothers me about this is that there is no apparent declaration in effect for `function()` at the point of the call in `main()`.  Without a declaration, C assumes the parameter is passed as an integer, and so should give a warning.  You could fix this in several ways—add a function declaration above main(), move the function definition above main, or put the declaration in a header file included before main().

Comment: sorry i updated with some of my real code (as best i could without posting 1300 lines of code)

Answer (score 2):

It's weird that this would fail. Have you tried re-ordering the functions or declaring `function` before use (before main):

```
void *function(void *prarm);
```

Comment: For the reasons @wallyk stated.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a *very* large stack frame:

```
char buff[3000600], data[3000000], url[1024], c[1];
```

That's almost 6MB - perhaps you are exceeding the default process stack size limit on FreeBSD? FreeBSD uses `SIGSEGV` to kill a process that exceeds this limit, and it would be detected when you write to a local variable that would cause the stack to be extended beyond the limit.  You can tweak the stack size limit in [`login.conf`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=login.conf&sektion=5).